# I keep getting a syntax error in this prepared statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, syntax-error, sql-insert

I think it could be from the "values" parenthesis but I don't know how to change it.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
String sql = "INSERT into Angajat"
           +"ID,Nume,Prenume,Adresa,IdDep"
           +"VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,id.getText());
pst.setString(2,nume.getText());
pst.setString(3,prenume.getText());
pst.setString(4,adresa.getText());
pst.setString(5,iddep.getText());
```

Comment: Hi,  could you please provide your ts

Comment: Hi, could you please provide your table DDL? I believe the problem is in the values passed as parameters.  For instance on top of my head there are: could you really define your id or it's auto generated?  Or are the other parameters all text???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses around the list of column names:

```
String sql = "INSERT into Angajat "
           +"(ID,Nume,Prenume,Adresa,IdDep)"
           //^----------------------------^
           +"VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you ! I was struggling for half an hour now.